# Fetching data from a web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

[image]

Suppose the given picture (consider the picture as a web page) is a web page. I have saved this web page to my HDD. Now I want to parse/copy data from a specific area from the web page and store it into the database accordingly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out the HTML Agility Pack:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

It allows you to parse HTML like you would XML using a psuedo form of XPath.

Comment: By "pseudo form of XPath" you really mean "totally broken implementation of XPath", right? :)

Comment: Well, I don't think they were going for 100% XPath, still better than nothing! :P

Comment: You'll have to look at their examples, I haven't used it in about 6 months or so, usually you just create a HtmlDocument and load the contents then get the root element and use SelectSingleNode etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can use an Html parser as the Html Agility Pack (htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to do it

HTH